# why the same $data array is passed to all views at the same time in codeigniter if i use template library created by phil?

Tags: php, codeigniter

why the same $data array is passed to all views at the same time in codeigniter if i use template library created by phil?

here is my code in my controller :

```
    $data['kutta'] = 'Kutta'; // i tried $data = array('kutta' => 'Kutta');
    $this->template->title('Blog', $title)
              ->set_layout('default')
              ->set_partial('header', 'jquery/table/sort_order',$data)
              ->build('jquery/notification/notification',$data);
```

actually when i pass the $data array only and only to my partial view then the view generated by build() also have the values and variables of $data array given to my partial and vice versa.
simply whatever $data array i pass to any of my view is become available to all the views, why it is happening?
you may found the phil's template library here : http://getsparks.org/packages/template/show
thanks in advance?

Comment: Is `$data` a reference? Once you reference-ize a variable in PHP, it stays a reference until you unset() it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the question is but there is nothing wrong with the code you posted.

The idea is that a partial is a little view fragment that does its own thing. The chances are this will not need ALL of the data for the entire page available. That slows down parsing and increases memory.

IF however you do need it to have the same data, then pass it the same data.

Comment: He's saying that passing data to one view makes it available to another view that didn't get data passed to it. The code block is misleading because he's passing it to both. Is this expected behavior, or does this even actually happen?

Comment: @wesley murch : Exactly... @phil sturgen : your templating library is outstanding, but you totally misunderstood my question

Comment: when i pass $data array to only my partial, the view present in build() method also get the values from my partial, and when i pass $data array to only to build() method then the partial also get the values from the $data array, but how it can happen if i havn't passed any data to the partial?

Comment: I'll put that one down to language barrier as your question was hard to understand :) It shouldn't do that, at least not in the latest version. If so, file a bug and I'll sort it out when I get around to it!